# How can I add new states for a country in OpenERP/Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I was trying to find the file where the states for US are charged to the data base , but I only found res.country.state.csv file, and I modified adding other record then restart the server, and nothing happened.
If anyone have a tutorial o pdf guide to help me. I would appreciate it very much.
Thanks...

Comment: what you need to do exactly? the res.country.state.csv contain the states of US.

Comment: Hi @Yacino
I'm from Peru, and I wanna filtering my States(Spanish: Departamentos) on a list like the states of US, How can I do it? thats why I was trying to see how US' states are charging, which are the steps to charge my STATES on OpenERP/Odoo by code, Thks

Comment: After many hours i got nothing, only the Class res_country, but I can't see where on this class are being calling the states, from where? res.country.state.csv? where is the mention of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States data are defined in ***res.country.state.csv*** file as you mentioned.

You can define a new file like this one or just modify it respecting that format.

To visualize your changes, don't forget to update base module (restarting server not enough).

If you create a new file don't forget to add it to data section in ***_ _openerp_ _.py***

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, I understand how Odoo modules work, on the official documentation for Odoo 8, don't explain how use csv.
Let me ask you.....When you add in **__openerp__.py** a csv file, this file is add on the database automatically?